# In GMail API, using Python 3, how do I skip to the last page of my results?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I am using GMail API to mine some informations like flights, receipts, invoices, ecc.
I want to skip a number of pages or skip to the very last one. How do I do that with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip pages by relying on the [nextPageToken](http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) field as described in the reference of the `list` call. The `nextPageToken` field is part of the response payload.

```
 query = 'example query has:attachment'
 nextPageToken = ''                                                                                                                                                         

  # The following while goes through all pages using the nextPageToken key in the response.
  while True:

  ### GET MESSAGES THAT MATCH A QUERY
      msg_results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=20, pageToken=nextPageToken, q=query).execute()
  #    messages = msg_results.get('messages', [])
      if('nextPageToken' in msg_results or nextPageToken==''):
          nextPageToken = msg_results['nextPageToken']
          print('nextPageToken={}'.format(nextPageToken))
      else:
          break
```

Once you've done this loop, your `msg_results` will contain only the messages that belong to the last page. How many messages you get will depend on how `maxResults` is set.

If you only want to skip a number of pages like 3 or 4 it's easy to change the above snippet to count the loops and quit when it's at the desired page.

To have a fully working code example you can try integrating the above snippet with [this code on GitHub](https://github.com/abhishekchhibber/Gmail-Api-through-Python/blob/master/gmail_read.py) or with the nice [boilerplate from GMail knowledge base](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) which is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/quickstart.py).